# Assistance in Fixing mistakes in HTML Project for school in DreamWeaverCS4

Tags: html, xhtml, dreamweaver, flash-cs5, cs4

Well I am trying to make the spry menu bars clickable an I got it working for only one of them but the rest are just a "#" at the end for the url and even if I go to the code myself an add the file manual like the other it still does not work.
Also if you can work fast an help me with this because I am getting very much errors on doing it.
here are files:
http://www.mediafire.com/?9vcdlewpe22lm2w
I cant seem to get the side bar an all the others to align center even if I code it in to.
Also the bottom links are empty I need to fill those up to.
OH BTW FIXED THE # OUTPUT

So pretty much I need help with the background colors.
Re centering the take in the body area
Adding correct heading etc for nav bar documents
the info that will be put on it I will do that I just need everything centered out right and background colors make the outer layer black. thanks so much I also deleted anything useless in the folder.

Oh yah also I havent got really any time to do this because of homework.
My teacher gives around 70 long question packets everyday he is gone an he is gone all week an I have tons other because I was pulled out of school on thursday and friday.
This is also due tomorow for me an the requirements for the site I had were:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/edmodo/Slough/checklist2.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=0CRWCTVCWB17SQPJGB82&Expires=1319001238&Signature=Hn30bQiKIMNL1Gcwl5JXmThdgsQ%3D

Please help me I usually have all A's but I an now going down to B's an B+'s an C+ I want to have all A's its just I havent got time to do all work for this week.

Thanks for helping me:)

NOT TRYING TO TELL YOU TO DO MY WORK IF ABLE TO JUST CORRECT SOME OF MY MISTAKES AN UPLOAD THEM THEN THANKS SO MUCH YOU SAVED ME TONS OF STRESS!

Comment: Can you edit your question and cut out the stuff that isn't your question? I tried to read it and all I got from it is you like to shorten the word "and" and you're really busy at school. An apparantly there's some files that you want me to download, unrar, fix some errors, and give them back so you can turn them in.

Answer (score 1):

I hope what you are doing is an inexperienced attempt at making something to meet deadlines and doesn't reflect what your teacher is showing you. (We all have to start somewhere, but if you are being taught to do it that way it is a different story completely)

first off, I would say chuck the dreamweaver spry stuff. It's useless drivel that can be done in css and only adds code bloat (as do most of the dreamweaver 'features').

I don't know what you can/can't use, however if possible I would recommend using a serverside language (php or ruby for example) to reduce code repitition, but that might be outside the scope of what needs to be done.

if we stick to HTML, I would recommend using the twitter bootstrap to give you a quick leg up in layout and navigation as well as base styles (look at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap). Using that, an external stylesheet and a bit of proper and consistant html you should be able to get something put together rather quickly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MYvk4/ should point you in the right direction. Just need to add the search, logo (I put text instead of an image, also use the alt tag to describe the image, and the longdesc only if there is a need for it). I am using html5 elements (with html5shiv). Again this is just a quick sample, and it could be much better, but I hope it's enough to get you on the right track. As for custom 404 error, that would need to be edited on the host that you will place it on (unless the teacher just wants a 404.html in the folder).